# Resize Height (equalHeights) jQuery

Tags: jquery

As I can change the height of the function (equalHeights) but you can resize.

**JQUERY:**

```
    $.fn.equalHeights = function () {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        // get the maximum height
        this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.height() > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = $this.height();
            }
        });
        // set the elements height
        this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.height(maxHeight);
        });
    };
```

**RESIZE:**

```
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            $("#layout .item").not("#layout .item.custom").find("img").equalHeights();
        });
    });
```

**EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/u8e1ju9b/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resizing your browser window to see how the blocks react.

http://sam152.github.io/Javascript-Equal-Height-Responsive-Rows/demo.html